# Firebase realtime database access not complete?

Tags: android, for-loop, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have an app that store 256 rows of number which indicate the background color of each 256 cells in a gridview. Currently all value are -16449536 which indicate black color for simplicity.

The following is my JSON structure in Firebase database

```
 "publicwall" : {
    "cell0" : -16449536,
    "cell1" : -16449536,

...........

    "cell254" : -16449536,
    "cell255" : -16449536

  },
```

In the onCreate method, i used a for loop to read 256 times for each cell:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
        final int position = i;
        DatabaseReference cell_color = mDatabase.child("publicwall").child("cell" + i);
        cell_color.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                ColorData = dataSnapshot.getValue(int.class);
                gridAdapter.notifyColorChange(ColorData, position);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
```

The result is as this pic:
[image: I expect all dots to be black]

Not all grids are black.
Everytime I re-open the app to trigger the onCreate method, the grid patterns are somehow different. Did I reached some limitations on the firebase realtime database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regardless of the problem in your current code, you're better off replacing the 256 (!!!) listeners with a single `ChildEventListener`:

```
mDatabase.child("publicwall").addChildEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
  public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String previousChildName) {
      String key = dataSnapshot.getKey();
      int position = Integer.parseInt(key.substring(4));
      ColorData = dataSnapshot.getValue(int.class);
      gridAdapter.notifyColorChange(ColorData, position);
  }
  public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
      String key = dataSnapshot.getKey();
      int position = Integer.parseInt(key.substring(4));
      ColorData = dataSnapshot.getValue(int.class);
      gridAdapter.notifyColorChange(ColorData, position);
  }
  ...
}
```

There are a few more methods you'll need to implement, but these are the most important ones to get started.

I recommend reading about [listening for lists of data in the Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#child-events).